# Is this a proper way for using "providing"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

This sentence sounds funny to me. The part that is bothering me is where it states "thus providing." Is this a correct use of "thus providing"?

> The reader obtains a better “feel” for the way Dillard interprets the
>   natural world, thus providing background and a foundation for the rest
>   of the novel.

Comment: Yes, the use of *thus providing* is correct, grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, unlike the commenters, that you have no doubt that "thus [verb]ing" is grammatically correct, but are concerned that "providing" *does not make sense*, that is, "providing" is not used properly, from a semantic standpoint.

On this, I agree with you whole-heartedly.

How can obtain[ing] **thus provide** anything?  Answer: it can't.

To whom is the reader *providing a background*? Answer: To nobody. He is *obtaining* that as well (but in WA2's rendering, apparently the reader is providing background *to himself*)

As commenters have shown, the only  way to make sense of this is to add or change words, or to imagine "missing" words.

I believe you can salvage the *provide* verb, but it needs to have as a subject *a better "feel"* rather than *the reader*.

To do this, simply add "which" amd change "providing" to "provides:

- The reader obtains a better "feel" for the way Dillard interprets the natural world, **which provides** background and a foundation for the rest of the novel.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.

As written, 'thus providing' belongs with the subject of the sentence ie the reader.

As I understand it, *background and a foundation for the rest of the novel*  comes from Dillard's interpretation of the natural world.

> The reader obtains a better “feel” for the way Dillard interprets the
>   natural world, and how it provides background and a foundation for the rest
>   of the novel.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you. Words have perhaps been elided.  *The reader obtains a better feel....thus providing (him or her with) background and a foundation for the rest of the novel*.

Comment: Also, the sentence is fine, grammatically, which I imagine was what the OP had in mind (*sounds funny* and *is this a correct use*). The sense of a sentence need not correspond to what we expect things to be like in our real-world experience. Even a nonsense sentence can be correct English.